# Why would a planet orbiting a black hole have a year lasting just over one month?

Tags: hard-science, orbital-mechanics

This question is based on this description of the Cormoran Supermassive Black Hole in the [Orion Arm's website](https://www.orionsarm.com/eg-article/5bab765b00ec3?fbclid=IwAR22GF0OL_XqUdsGyepYpE-waApNIOLFrwr7SQBefN_qSbyy9rLCDTC4qLg):

> Orbiting the black hole in hundreds of concentric circles are more
> than a million planets, some slightly warmer than Earth-like in
> temperature and many much colder, but most are temperate and capable
> of supporting a hydrosphere. The circle of planets that is most
> Earth-like in temperature orbits at a distance of 67 AU, and each
> planet completes an orbit in 44.7 days, travelling at 5%c.

This I never understood.  The further a body is from its parent, the longer it takes to complete an orbit.  By that logic, ergo, a planet orbiting a star from a distance of 67 AUs should have a revolution lasting *over 548 **years!***  So why should a planet orbiting a black hole 20 million times as massive as our sun from a distance of 6,231,000,000 miles have a year lasting just over one month?

*Oh, and before suggesting that I ask this to the Astronomy Stack Exchange, we have found no evidence of planets orbiting black holes from a safe distance in real life, and Astronomy doesn't really do fiction, at least not without a specific line of reference.*

Comment: The stronger the gravity, the faster you have to go sideways to miss for any given distance.

Comment: What's with the close votes?

Comment: @JohnWDailey: Because it's basic physics, or perhaps astronomy?  But might get closed there because it's just TOO basic.

Comment: @jamesqf  Not to me.

Comment: I don't get the close votes either. This seems like a perfectly ordinary & cliche "orbital mechanics" query.  Unless you're asking specifically about the fictional star system you linked to, in which case, you're asking about someone else's fictional world, which is off topic here!  Am going to assume the former and VTR.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on @lijat's answer:

The formula for orbital period is $T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{\alpha ^ 3}{GM}}$ where $\alpha$ is the semi-major axis, $G$ is the gravitational constant, and $M$ is the mass of the more massive body.  So while the period of the orbit grows according to the root of the cube of the axis, it also is *reduced* the greater the mass of the body being orbited.

At twenty million times the mass of our sun, orbital periods are going to be *radically* reduced until $\alpha$ grows very large indeed.

Comment: For a point of reference, if Earth orbit weren't well within the Roche limit of such a black hole, if you replaced the sun with this black hole, Earth's year would be about two hours long.

Comment: Upvoted, looks like sound reasoning to me.. but maybe (now follows a stupid remark from a non-astronomer) an orbital radius α below a certain distance is not allowed anyway ? is the orbit stable ? would this planet not go spiral into the black hole relatively quickly ?

Comment: @Goodies - any orbital distance can be stable in a vacuum.  An object can scream around a black hole just above the event horizon if its angular velocity is close to the speed of light.  The thing that generally prohibits close orbits is the [Roche Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit), where the object would be torn apart, not anything intrinsic about orbital stability at a given axis.

Comment: (So the hypothetical object orbiting just above the event horizon would have to be incredibly, magically durable to do so, but nothing about the _orbit_ would be unstable.)

Comment: Aha so this scenario is theory only.. because a planet would never have enough angular velocity to start with, to get into such an tight orbit..  When there is a black hole, either the sun has collapsed - in that case nothing would change, mass and distance don't change - or the black hole is a visitor entering the system with a very large velocity. You'd get planets following the black hole's path and if they reach an orbits at all, it will become elongated/elliptical.. with possibly a longer orbit duration than before the black hole visited..

Comment: @jdunlop No, you can't orbit just above the event horizon of any black hole.  Black holes have an [Innermost Stable Circular Orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innermost_stable_circular_orbit) at 3 times the Schwarzschild radius for the non-rotating case, where the effects of general relativity mean that, left to gravity, orbital energy , and angular momentum, you're headed for the event horizon.

Comment: For real-world examples in the other direction - that is, orbiting a very light body - consider the DAWN spacecraft orbiting Vesta & Ceres, and the several other missions that have orbited asteroids & comets.

Comment: @notovny - you can't maintain a _circular_ orbit around a black hole that is just above the event horizon, but that doesn't discount a stable elliptical orbit.  All of this assuming, of course, no additional bodies perturbing the orbit.

Comment: An elliptical orbit will not save you, even without other perturbing bodies.  The Innermost stable circular orbit is where, if everything is exactly perfect, you can still have a stable orbit. If your elliptical orbit crosses into that region, your orbit may last awhile, but it's not going to last indefinitely. General relativity can be politely ignored far from black holes, but not that close.

Comment: @jdunlop I'm like a Newtonian fossil on these topics, but I would imagine a close orbit around a black hole cannot be regarded as orbit in vacuum. There's an accretion disk.. every goaround the planet would be hit 2x by that (=friction=slowing down=lowering orbit)

Comment: @Goodies - this is a theoretical problem anyway, so we can discard the accretion disk.  (Also, the inability to maintain a stable orbit within thrice the Schwarzschild radius, as notovny correctly pointed out, means that there is no accretion disk within that radius.)

Comment: Correction: Looks like Elliptical orbits work down to [twice the Schwarzschild radius](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/677420/how-close-to-a-black-hole-can-an-object-orbit-elliptically) on a non-rotating black hole, though  they precess something fierce.

Answer (score 4):

The orbital period depends on the mass of the parent body as well as the distance. [Kepler’s third law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion) tells us that it varies with the square root of the mass, so take the square root of your mass difference of 20 million and you get 4,472. Divide 548 years by that and you should be expecting an orbital period of 0.12 of a year, which is indeed a bit over a month.